# Unable to pass data from api to ng2-charts

Tags: angular, api, graph, ng2-charts

This is my **ng2-chart** static data in **component.ts** file :

```js
  public mbarChartLabels:string[] = ['June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November'];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  public barChartColors:Array<any> = [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(95, 103, 245, 0.5)',
      borderColor: '#5200cc',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fafafa',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fafafa',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177)'
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(128, 237, 104,0.5)',
      borderColor: '#208000',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)'
    }
];
  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [100,80,50,60,70,80], label: 'Approved'},
    {data: [60,80,80,30,40,90], label: 'Discounted'}
  ];
```

This is my Api call from which I am receiving data:

```js
    this._auth.approved_discounted().toPromise().then((res:any)=>{
      if(res){
        this.approved = parseInt(res["Approved"])
        this.discounted = parseInt(res["Discounted"])

        console.log(this.approved+" "+this.discounted)
       }
    });
```

Here, I am trying to insert this.approved & this.discounted data into the ng2-chart but its receiving it. How to merge my API data in the ng2-chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your html is rendered before receiving data. You can use a boolean to wait for data and load html elements after it.

```
this.loadData = true;
this._auth.approved_discounted().toPromise().then((res:any)=>{
      if(res){
        this.approved = parseInt(res["Approved"])
        this.discounted = parseInt(res["Discounted"])

        console.log(this.approved+" "+this.discounted)
       }
       this.loadData = false;
    });
```

and in your html:

`<canvas *ngIf="!loadData"></canvas>` // or your "chart" tag

offtopic:

> I don't know why you use Promise (probably you come from plain js or
>   React/AngularJs). Try to use Observables, this is specific for
>   Angular. And namings ... "approved_discounted", this is not for
>   Angular, this is for php or any other. Use approvedDiscounted - [Angular
>   Coding Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)